# Deploying Word Document Using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I have completed making a word document in visual studio which I would like to be able to install easily on a number of computers. I am unsure as to how I am supposed to create an installer.I tired using just the build  release( which contains the setup, the document itself, the vsto file and a folder called application files)and this worked to an extent but it does not allow me to install on computers without unblocking all the elements in the release and even then only works about half the time.  I tried using the instructions found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx which worked well for me earlier when creating an outlook Add-In however the final result of this was just a setup and a windows installer  without and document to use. The document does reside in bin\release and works there however, when i remove it from this folder it no longer works. What am I doing wrong and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the Word document to a VS Project as a resource (Build Action).

Upon application start, save the resource to a temporary file and open it.

The Application could be published using click once deployment.